# Detect shapes based on their equations in an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, detection, curve-fitting

EDIT: Detection of triangle, rectangle/square or any other with sharp edges can be detected, **but I'm not getting how to detect the spiral.**

Is it possible to **detect different shapes** based on the general equation of the shape. Like for example if I give a **general equation** of a circle/ rectangle/ triangle/ spiral or any other shape, is it possible to detect that shape in an image?

*For example if I give a general equation of the shapes, it should detect the shape in the image*.
More precisely defining the problem: If I give a general equation of a triangle, it should detect the triangle and mark it.

Here's a sample input image.

[image]

I know that using some morphological analysis and edge detection is very easy for this but **I have to use curve fitting**, but I'm not able to know how to start, can anyone please provide an algorithm or a snippet please.

Answer (score 1):

You get line detection using the `hough()` function and circle detection using `imfindcircles()` in the Image Processing Toolbox.

Alternatively, you can turn this problem around: first detect objects of interest by some means, e. g. by color, and then try to identify their shape. The `regionprops()` function can compute many different shape characteristics for you.

And if all else fails, you can write your own [Generalized Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_Hough_transform)

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but i need to do that by curve fitting.
THe problem statement is to detect shape based on the given general equation.

Comment: You can still detect object of interest, use `bwtraceboundary` to get their boundary pixels, and then use curve fitting to see what type of shape fits best.

Comment: The above mentioned image is an ideal one, what if similar objects like a match box or cyclone of egg is to be detected using a general equation of a rectangle or spiral or oval?
(For the use of others)

Comment: In that case, you are going to have to implement your own Generalized Hough Transform. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_Hough_transform